# How to stop page refresh when hit enter button from rich:inputNumberSpinner field?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsf, refresh

I use **rich:inputNumberSpinner** tag.

The problem is :

I set cursor focus to inside of *rich:inputNumberSpinner* field, then i hit the enter button from my keyboard, that time page will be automatically refresh.

But i don't need page refresh when i hit the enter button from my keyboard.

The code :

**spinnerTagTest.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html>
      <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">              
     </head>
<body>
      <h:form id="SpinnerForm">                                  
              <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="spinnerField" value="" />              
      </h:form>
</body> </html></f:view>
```

I also use rich:hotKey for that inputNumberSpinner field. But Page refreshed.

```
<rich:hotKey key="return"
             selector="#spinnerField"
             handler="event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();
             return false;"/>
```

And i check anotherway using javasccript, but page refreshed.

The specific tag and javascript is :

```
<rich:inputNumberSpinner id="spinnerField"  value="" 
                         oninputkeypress="return stopPageRefresh();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function stopPageRefresh()
    {
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Here i use one alert message inside of stopPageRefresh().
But i hit enter button, first page refreshing and then alert message displayed.

Help me about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a JSF expert, but I think the problem is only related to client-side JavaScript.

In several browsers you [cannot prevent default *actions*](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html#t07) using `onkeypress` (in some browsers you can, in some browsers this is the only way of preventing default actions). Anyway, this is a great mess with a lot of differences between browsers.

Following code will add the appropriate event handler to `spinnerField`. Run it inside an `onload` event handler, or at least after `spinnerField` is rendered.

```
if (window.opera)
  document.getElementById("spinnerField").onkeypress = noEnter;
else
  document.getElementById("spinnerField").onkeydown = noEnter;

function noEnter(e) {
  var event = e || window.event;

  if (event.keyCode == 13)
    return false;
}
```

*Update:* Possibly you have to set the [`cancelBubble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533545%28VS.85%29.aspx) property in IE to fully prevent submitting on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I'm not sure about that. If the above example doesn't work properly in Microsoft's product, replace `noEnter` with:

```
function noEnter(e) {
  var event = e || window.event;

  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. 
But i test one alert message inside of your script. 
That alert also called after refreshing the page.

Comment: @eswa: Alert message? Where do you put that line?

Comment: After open the braces, i add the alert message.

funtion noEnter(e)
{
  alert("start process...");
  //Here i use your code 
}

Comment: @eswa: In that case, the alert will pop up on every key press. E.g., if you place it inside the `if` block, it will only fire when you press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Just i modify your script like add one alert message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.onkeydown=noEnter;
if (window.opera)
      document.getElementById("spinnerField").onkeypress = noEnter;
else
     document.getElementById("spinnerField").onkeydown = noEnter;

function noEnter(e)
{
      alert("start...");
      var event = e || window.event;
      if (event.keyCode == 13)
      {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: Here before open the popup (alert), page refreshed.

Comment: I feel this is JSF component related problem.
If you know jsf related forum, then please can you mentioned.
Help me.

Comment: You shouldn't attach an `onkeydown` event in every case… Moreover, this way the alert will pop up on every key press. If you place it inside the if block, it will only fire when you press Enter.

Comment: Do you have an example page, so we can look at the actually generated HTML?

Comment: ok. That case also i check it. Like, i insert alert message in inside of if block. when i hit enter button from that rich:inputNumberSpinner field, then first page refreshed, and then alert winwow open.

Comment: In which browser? And still, do you have an example page, so we can check this?

Answer (score 0):

it can be fixed by Richfaces library update (at least for the RF 3.x). You have to fix the sources in RF and rebuild it.
it works for me

1. Download RichFaces sources
2. Extract them and navigate to the file in which form-submission is done
   “ui/inputnumber-spinner/src/main/resources/org/richfaces/renderkit/html/script/SpinnerScript.js”
3. comment this.edit.form.submit();

   ```
       if (e.keyCode == 13){
       if (this.spinner.required || "" != this.edit.value)
           this.edit.value = this.getValidValue(this.edit.value);
       if (this.edit.form) {
           this.edit.form.submit(); //!!comment it
       }
   }
   ```

   }

rebuild the richfaces

see details here http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/disable-enter-form-submit-fix-inputnumberspinner/